# Laravel 7 Cache via Middleware is not accessing the cached content and send X-Proxy-Cache: MISS header

Tags: caching, laravel-7

I have tried implementing cache on the Laravel 7 app via the middleware.

As I can see the key is being created and content is cached inside `storage/framework/cache` directory under `/data/b4/91/b491d9177c0ac28e06b7ab7f9992a902230a56b`c key, which when opened includes the content of the page I am trying to cache.

Here is my middleware class:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class CacheResponse
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ttl=1440)
    {
        if(auth()->user() != null || $request->isMethod('post'))
            return $next($request);
        $params = $request->query(); unset($params['_method']); ksort($params);
        $key = md5(url()->current().'?'.http_build_query($params));
        if($request->get('_method')=='purge')
            Cache::forget($key);
        if(Cache::has($key)){
            $cache = Cache::get($key);
            $response = response($cache['content']);
            $response->header('X-Proxy-Cache', 'HIT');
        }
        else {
            $response = $next($request);
            if(!empty($response->content()))
                Cache::put($key,['content' => $response->content()],$ttl);
            $response->header('X-Proxy-Cache', 'MISS');
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the last condition in the if statement does not seem to be able to get the cached content as `Cache::has($key)` always returned false even though the key exists. When I try to `dd(Cache::has($key))` the cached file `b491d9177c0ac28e06b7ab7f9992a902230a56b` is removed from the cache leaving only the empty `/data/b4/91/` directory in `storage/framework/cache/`

More Information:

the cache parameter is applied via route `Route::get('/', 'Client\HomePageController@getMain')->middleware('cacheable:5');`

and middleware is registered in `app/Http/Kernel.php` file under the `$routeMiddleware` array as `'cacheable'=> \App\Http\Middleware\CacheResponse::class`

help, please

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem some years ago. I managed to work around it. The reason why you can't access the Cache system in middleware is because your boot process is not completed yet. That's how I found out that Storage is available. Thus in `config/filesystem.php` I added this disk:

```
'cache'  => [
        'driver'     => 'local',
        'root'       => storage_path('app/framework/cache'),
    ],
```

It's the same place where Cache puts its data. As such, if you save a 'key', you can do this with `Storage::disk('cache')->put($key, $data);`. Retrieve it in your middleware with `Storage::disk('cache')->get($key);`

Maybe some people will disagree with my suggestion. But this workaround has served me for years without failure. Is somebody has a better way, please share.

**Edit**: I dropped some disk requirements to the minimum. My storage system has another reason as well. But these settings would be sufficient. This disk can't be public because its no part of the public folders of a Laravel project.